# How to display ACF field outside metabox

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

is it possible to display ACF field outside Metabox? For example in custom modal widnow.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if you can display the content of a ACF field in a metabox? Or the actual field so a user on the front end can edit the value?

Displaying values from ACF can be easily done with the get_field() and the_field() functions from ACF. If its an array, you can print_r and see how to get what you need out.

```
$textvalue = get_field( "text_field" );
$array = get_field( "array_field" );

echo $textvalue;
print_r($array);
```

If you mean displaying the field on the front end - you would have to build a form and a handler to make the change. Or use something like gravityforms, which has all sorts of built in functionality to update posts.

Comment: First, thanks for your answer, but the situation is little bit different.

I want to use ACF for populating my custom Modal window in admin. I want to have the fields in my custom modal window instead of metaboxes.

Comment: You might be able to do this by loading the js / css for your modal, wrapping the necessary divs around the metabox, and inserting a trigger link into your editor page.

This might be worth doing as a custom field type in ACF.

It would actually be easier to do this with CMB2 since you have to actually provide the markup for the fields that loads into the editor page.